# Save image in database directly or to save image path? SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using C# .NET v3.5, SQL SERVER 2008. My team is creating Point Of Sale Windows Application for Restaurant and Super Markets, so there will be a huge amount of pictures in the application. For which,  I want to know which will be better in terms of responsiveness, saving the images directly in database or to save image paths in the database.

I'll appreciate your response.

Thank you!

Sarmad Asif

Comment: What work you have done so far ???

Comment: Possible duplicate [storing images in db yea or nay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As of me Save Image in paths will be better.**

I already gone through these phase. We develop Jewellery Software in which we also have huge amount of image. We first store image in DB but then its very difficult to do daily backups as well as restore once size grows. We tried our level best with SQL2008 to take backup without FileStream and try to restore it but we didn't succeed. And last we have changed our logic for image should show from Path.

Comment: Thank You Snehal. It always occurred to me that this would be the answer but was unsure. I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

Better to save image paths in the database and retrieve the path from db and take the image from the responsive paths.

Answer (score 0):

If the you have small images then use Varbinary, otherwise use FileStream.
see this:
https://www.google.com/#q=sql%20server%20filestream%20vs%20varbinary

This is a good book will really help you:
http://download.red-gate.com/ebooks/SQL/Art_of_SS_Filestream_Sebastian_and_Aelterman.pdf

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)